# When to use $Δt$ in equations?

Tags: kinematics, time, notation

For some equations, such as $d=vt$, simply $t$ is used, representing time. But in the equation $a=\Delta V/\Delta t$, $Δt$ is used rather than $t$. My question is what is practically the difference between $Δt$ and $t$, and why would one use on over another?

Comment: $t$ is usually understood as an _overall_ time, and $d$ as an _overall_ distance. Hence $d = vt$ relates the _average_ speed $v$ to $d$ and $t$. When you want to consider a time interval, and the variation of a quantity within that time interval, the $\Delta$ notation is used. When $\Delta t$ tends to zero one starts getting at the notion of _derivative_.

Comment: Technically all spatial and time measurements are relative, so it would be correct to always use $\Delta t$. In context it depends on whether it matters for the understanding of a physical scenario.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

As you see, there is no generally accepted convention.  Mine is to use $x$ when I refer to a coordinate :  $$x_f = x_i + \bar{v}(t_f - t_i)$$ and  $\Delta x$ when we are referring to an interval. $$ \Delta x = \bar{v}\Delta t$$
I make the point to students that the coordinate values depend on the choice of origin, while the $\Delta$ version does not.  Nature, of course, doesn't care where I put the origin, so the latter version better reflects the nature of physical law.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official convention about such use. $\Delta t$ usually indicates a smallish but finite time difference or interval, often in contrast to $\delta t$ which is a very small (ideally infinitesimal) time interval. As CuriousOne points out, all time measurements are intervals, but $t$ or $T$ are customarily used for long intervals or as time markers - eg $t_1, t_2, t_3$ etc seconds after $t=0$.

Comment: Personally, I think $\Delta t$ should refer to a time interval of any length.  Certainly there is no restriction on it in the definition of average velocity.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you generally use $Δt$ but if your initial moment is when $t1=0$ then ($Δt = t2-t1$ where $t1$ is your initial moment and $t2$ your last moment) $Δt = t2 - 0$ so for simplicity we write $t2$ . So its for example $Δx =  u Δt$ but when $t1=0 => Δx = u t$ now if also $x1=0 => x=ut$